# Change datas in a big sheet-list per GoogleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Helo,

I try to change any data in a very big list. For this job I have create this script:

```js
function myProjLibreVersion() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BigList");

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue()=="ProjectLibre") {
      Browser.msgBox("found a Value Row ="+i +"\\nColoumn = 4");
      sheet.getRange(i,4).activate();
    }
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Jup");
 }
```

But my problem is the list is so big and the google settings always break my script - error: Exceeded maximum execution time.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve my problem?

Here is the link to a example-list and my script (tools/script editor): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cs_LB8VxDtssjt8dBqTk7I2nHqbNj5eyva4XIlWd1u4/edit#gid=0

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function myProjLibreVersion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("BigList");
  const rg = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let html = '';
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[3] == "ProjectLibre") {
      html += `<br>Row: ${i+1} Column: 4`;
    }
  });
  if(html.length>0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"ProjectLibre")
  }
 }
```

Comment: Cool. I'd change the part `getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());` with `getDataRange();` Does it make sense? What do you think?

Comment: I would normally but I suspect that they have headers and if they do this is easier to change

Comment: This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will probably explain it better than I can.  All of the array methods are well worth learning.  You really can get a lot more done with a lot less coding.

Comment: wowww - exact what I need - perfect thanks - I've studied the script and it looks very logical. However, I get stuck with the variable "r" (vs.forEach ((r, i) => {". Could you please explain the" r "to me in brief words?

Answer (score 0):

The sheet is not so big actually. You need to use `var array = getValues()` instead of `getValue()` and iterate then through this `array`.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

Something like this:

```
function myProjLibreVersion() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BigList");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  var lr = data.length;
  var lc = data[0].length;

  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    if (data[i][3] == "ProjectLibre") {
      Browser.msgBox("found a Value Row =" + i +"\\nColoumn = 4");
      // sheet.getRange(i,4).activate(); // <-- I'm not sure what this for
    }
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Jup");
}
```